# How to create a column of the last/right-most non-empty values in every row from a whole range

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Say I have this spreadsheet, where the column I'm trying to create is column `E`.

```
A B C D E
z   z   z
x x   z z
y       y
y x     x
```

How would I go about this in google sheets? I've seen some answers to similar questions about combining INDEX and MATCH but I can't figure it out.

Also needs to work on a sheet with over 100k rows so I can't just drag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(SPLIT( 
   CONCATENATE(IF(LEN(B3:F9),"★"&B3:F9,)&REPT(" "&"♣︎",COLUMN(B3:F3)=COLUMN(F3))),"♣︎")))),".*★(.+)$","$1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solution posted by marikamitsos, you could also try

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(regexextract(trim(transpose(query(transpose(substitute(B3:E," ", "_")),,9^99))), "[^\s]*$"), "_", " "))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't _quite_ work as `cccc dddd eeee` in one cell returns `eeee` instead of the whole cell value.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo: I updated my answer. Please check again.

Comment: wow I really would have never figured this out. Thank you.